# Laravel - Unable to complete upload to S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images through my Laravel app locally to my S3 bucket. However, it keeps returning me `Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the GetObject operation: [Key] expected string length to be >= 1, but found string length of 0`. And some debugging data I got from running dd(), it returned me a boolean value of `false`, which is *strange*. I'm not sure why.

This is the code I am running to get an image uploaded to S3 and have the path stored in my database:

```
if ($request->has('avatar'))
{

       // Get the path to the file
       $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('attachments', 's3');
            
       // Set visibility => public
       $disk = Storage::disk('s3'); 
       Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($path, 'public');

       /** @var \Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager $disk */
       $url = $disk->url($path);
       $inputFields['avatar'] = $url;

}

Image::create($inputFields);

return back();
```

This is my Route:

```
// Update user profile
Route::post('/users/{user}/upload/avatar', [UserController::class, 'store']);
```

This is my upload form:

```
<form action="/users/{{ $user->id }}/upload/avatar" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="space-y-4">
 @csrf
 <div class="flex flex-col items-start space-y-1">
  <label for="" class="font-semibold">Update profile picture</label>
  <input type="file" name="avatar" class="border rounded-md w-full">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-md bg-blue-600 text-white">Upload</button>
</form>
```

I've also tried re-creating buckets, changing bucket access, setting permissions and create a couple of users with full access to any of the buckets.

Any suggestions, or tips, I would be so humbled to learn from. I also look to help others who are facing the same situation with some positive results after learning from this. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with your framework, but the error message indicates that you're trying to retrieve an object whose name is the empty string.  Are you sure that the request that's failing comes from the code that you quoted above?  I only see code that tries to *write* to S3.  Does the object actually get created in S3?  That might help you narrow down which line of code is causing the error.

Comment: The object actually does not get created, however a path/url to the object is created, which is strange. I've gone through many scenarios to fix it like checking my .env, config, etc. Still no luck.

Comment: Actually show the stacktrace to the error from your laravel.log. show which variable you checked with dd(). Try to dd() earlier, there's a reason why it's returning false

Comment: I've actually dd() to see if the file was uploaded to S3, which I came to realize that it is supposed to be a boolean value. So it is returning false indicating that it was not uploaded to S3. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file with public visibility using the following syntax https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#file-visibility

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->storePublicly('attachments', 's3');

$url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);
```